# Can turmeric help you get better?

Tags: herbalism

Looking at a couple of sites it states:

[PaleoHacks](http://blog.paleohacks.com/9-herbs-that-naturally-kill-parasites/#)

> This is perhaps one of the most powerful herbs and is helpful for just about 
>       everything. It boasts powerful properties. it is an anticancer, anti-
>       inflammatory, wound-healing, worm-expelling, and an overall body purifier. 
>       This is a very safe herb to consume regularly for maintaining health as well 
>       as to use medicinally. Pair with coconut oil and black pepper for improved 
>       absorption

It cites reference to https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26261481 but that does not talk about the effects on bacteria (or so I can tell). The other link http://www.drlise.net/attachments/tumeric.pdf seems broken

Also the uncited page http://naturalon.com/top-10-natural-cures-for-removing-internal-parasites/view-all/ says

> Turmeric has a multitude of health benefits and one of them is for the 
>       treatment of parasitic infections

I have had an in-law also "encourage" us to put tumeric in our toddlers milk because it raises body temperature which can assist in killing off a cold, which I imagine is viral which I cannot see is possible (unless it boosts the immuse system). Found a site that says the same: http://www.naturalnews.com/048186_warming_spices_body_temperature_herbal_medicine.html

Is there any truth to having tumeric to assist in killing "bugs" (including raising body temperature), either bacterial or viral?

Comment: "Just about everything" -- no. I now have to look up "turmeric", but, no. ;-)

Comment: Also, "personal medical questions and health advice are off-topic on Skeptics. We can not safely answer questions for your specific situation and you should always consult a doctor for medical advice."

Comment: Whenever someone is trying to sell you a herbal miracle cure and "Purifier" then it's very safe to assume that they're full of it and looking to make some money selling their snake oil

Comment: There's some information on Wikipedia about this (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turmeric#Research and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curcumin#Research); can you let us know what additional information you'd be looking for in an answer?

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) In order to answer this question, we would need to see studies of Turmeric's effect on thousands of diseases. Please limit this to one claim.

Comment: Related: [Turmeric and Depression](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/23051/is-turmeric-better-than-prozac-to-treat-depression)

Comment: If someone offers you a "herb" that will "cure cancer", you can pretty much stop listening to them there. The sheer amount of things they clearly don't understand about cancer guarantees that whatever else they'll say after that will be either wrong or false and you might as well save yourself the time.

Comment: [Topical XKCD](https://www.xkcd.com/1217/)

Comment: @Magisch: The profit motive would seem to be negligible here, since turmeric is available at my grocery store (WinCo) for around $3/lb.  There's some creditable research showing that turmeric & other curcuminoids do have some positive health effects (see Google or Google Scholar), but it's by no means a universal miracle cure - otherwise there would be no sick Indians :-)

Comment: Sorry for the question being too broad, not sure how to phrase it better. Happy to close the question.